# Hover on svg text not working

Tags: svg

Creating a svg from adobe xd and trying to create a hover effect for the svg can change fill: colors on hover.

**# Heres the svg code #**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="1563 3492 45 45">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #79bf73;
        font-size: 45px;
        font-family: SegoeMDL2Assets, Segoe MDL2 Assets;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <text id="E1CC" class="cls-1" transform="translate(1563 3537)"><tspan x="0" y="0"></tspan></text>
</svg>
```

**# Heres the html code #**

```
<div class="play">
   <img src="http:localhost/mockup3/images/E101.svg" height="42" width="42">
</div>
```

**# Heres the css code #**

```
svg text #E101:hover{

    fill: #003565;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVGs inserted as `img` can't have interaction, they behave as images. To fix this, simply put the full SVG code inline. Cleaned up the code a bit, as these tools often produce ugly code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="play">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="1563 3492 45 45" width="42" height="42">
    <text id="E1CC" class="cls-1" transform="translate(1563 3537)"><tspan x="0" y="0"></tspan></text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
svg text {
    fill: #79bf73;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family: SegoeMDL2Assets, Segoe MDL2 Assets;
}

svg text:hover{
    fill: #003565;
}
```

Keep in mind the icon will only be visible with the font `Segoe MDL2 Assets` installed.